# how to write a permutation in matrix notation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the permutation σ = (1, 3, 4)(3, 5) ∈ S5. 
a) Express the permutation σ using matrix notation 
b) Find σ2 
c) Write out the cyclic subgroup generated by σ

help please 
the 3 going to 4 and to 5 is throwing me off

Comment: The exercise is asking you to compose the two permutations $(1\;3\;4)$ and $(3\;5)$.

Comment: Have you learned how to write $(1 3 4)(3 5)$ as a product of disjoint cycles?

Comment: Find the permutation for $\sigma$ (what is $\sigma(i)$?), then permute either the columns or the rows of the identity matrix according to $\sigma$.